# Book about the history of mathematics for weather prediction

Tags: reference-request, applied-mathematics

Can someone recommend a book about the history of mathematics being used for weather prediction, preferable one which covers recent developments?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Invisible in the Storm: The Role of Mathematics in Understanding Weather](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/9957.html)

one [review (AMS)](http://www.ams.org/notices/201308/rnoti-p1051.pdf) a second [review (EMS)](http://www.euro-math-soc.eu/review/invisible-storm-role-mathematics-understanding-weather),

> "Invisible in the Storm" recounts the history,
>   personalities, and ideas behind one of the greatest scientific
>   successes of modern times - the use of mathematics in weather
>   prediction. Although humans have tried to forecast weather for
>   millennia, mathematical principles were used in meteorology only after
>   the turn of the twentieth century. From the first proposal for using
>   mathematics to predict weather, to the supercomputers that now process
>   meteorological information gathered from satellites and weather
>   stations, the authors Ian Roulstone and John Norbury narrate the groundbreaking
>   evolution of modern forecasting.